# jaxb Marshalling xs:any in spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jaxb

All,
I am trying to generate xml output like -

```
<Row>
    <City>Boston</City>
    <Runners>7000</Runners>
</Row>
```

The generated type from xsd is :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RowType", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class RowType {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }

}
```

Unmarshalling works fine, while marshalling it gives output like below.

```
<Row>
    <any>
        <name>CITY</name>
        <declaredType>java.lang.String</declaredType>
        <scope>javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope</scope>
        <value>Boston</value>
        <nil>false</nil>
        <globalScope>true</globalScope>
        <typeSubstituted>false</typeSubstituted>
    </any>
    <any>
        <name>RUNNERS</name>
        <declaredType>java.lang.String</declaredType>
        <scope>javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope</scope>
        <value>7000</value>
        <nil>false</nil>
        <globalScope>true</globalScope>
        <typeSubstituted>false</typeSubstituted>
    </any>
</Row>
```

Any idea how I could make this work with Spring boot ?

Comment: It is rather inconvenient to generate an xsd from a (very simple) xml - as you see the result is "quite generic". Normally you would write your xsd "by hand" or generate it from a "fine" jaxb(-annotated) class.

Answer (score 0):

POJO generated is not right. It should have been

**RowType:**

```
public class RowType
{
    private Row Row;

    public Row getRow ()
    {
        return Row;
    }

    public void setRow (Row Row)
    {
        this.Row = Row;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Row = "+Row+"]";
    }
}
```

**Row.java:**

```
public class Row
{
    private String Runners;

    private String City;

    public String getRunners ()
    {
        return Runners;
    }

    public void setRunners (String Runners)
    {
        this.Runners = Runners;
    }

    public String getCity ()
    {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity (String City)
    {
        this.City = City;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Runners = "+Runners+", City = "+City+"]";
    }
}
```

Cross check with this tool : http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with it.  If I create my own Jaxb marshaller and marshal it , it prints fine  Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(....).createMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(outputType,System.out);